# D3 Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I got this error while I try to plot a rectangle :

```
var row = svg.selectAll('.row')
               .data(data)
               .enter()
               .append('svg:g')
               .attr('class', 'row')

var col = row.selectAll('.cell')
               .data(function(d) { return d; })
               .enter().append('rect')
               .attr('class', 'cell')

               .attr('x', function(d){
                  return xscale(d[1]);
                })
               .attr('y', function(d){
                 return yscale(d[0]);
                })
               .attr('width', cellw)
               .attr('height', cellh)
               .attr('fill', function(d){
                return zscale(d[2]);
               })
```

I think the error is on the line `.attr('x', function(d)`

data is an array of array like [[Id1, Date1, Speed1], [...], ...] that I got from parsing a CSV file.

```
Data: [Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3]]

0: 1
1: Sun Jan 18 1970 01:32:42 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)
2: 10
```

And here is the xscale :

```
var xscale = d3.time.scale()
                     .domain([start, end])
                     .range([padding, w - padding]);
```

where start and end are also dates :

`start: Sun Jan 18 1970 01:32:42 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)
 start: object
 end: Sun Jan 18 1970 01:32:44 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)
 end: object`

Comment: You have to parse your string to date. Something like this: `var parse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse;` and then, inside the attribute, `xscale(parse(d[1]))`. Note: this is just an example, you have to correctly format your string with the proper specifiers (check here: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md).

Comment: But I already use Dates in data : `data.push([results["data"][idx]["Ids"], new Date(results["data"][idx]["Time"]), results["data"][idx]["Speed"]]);`